# Pick up only one control from 'css' class and remove it

Tags: sharepoint-server, css

In my sharepoint list in the dispform.aspx , I have the headers like : title,body,send email .
I want to remove only 'send email' field using css . when i checked in the developer tool , it showed that it is under '.ms-standardheader' class . when i set it to 'display:none' . It removes all other headers along with 'send email'. I just want to remove one header , how can i achieve it, how can i pick up only one control . nth child or what. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the site where the list exist using SharePoint Designer. From the left menu, select `List and Libraries` and find the list where you wanna edit the form.

Click on the list and you should see 3 forms available in the window called "Forms" that will include DispForm.aspx, EditForm.aspx and NewForm.aspx.

You won't be able to modify the columns on any of these so you will have to create a new one. Select `New` and select the type of form to create to `Display item form (used to view list items)` and then mark `Set as default form for the selected type`.

Click on save. Now you should have a fourth form under `Views`, right click on it and select `Edit file in advanced mode`.

Now find your column `send email` and the HTML should look something like this (I'm using a Title column for my example):

```
<tr>
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>Title</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

On the header line with the `nobr` tags, add a new `td` tag so it looks like this.

```
   <tr>
        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                                <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                    <td style="display:none;"><nobr>Title</nobr></td>
                                </H3>
                            </td>
                            <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Save and make sure that the new form is set to the default.

Comment: thanks , but its not working . even if i put display:none !important.

Comment: Is the list added as a webpart on a page or is it the defaults list location? is the column name "Send Mail" or "send mail"?

Comment: And it might be as simple as i typed "send mail" instead of "send email".

Comment: list is added as a default OOB custom list not as a webpart. And column name is 'Send Email' type : its a checkBox ,i typed it the way you showed .i tried putting that script in the Content Editor webpart as well . but nothing's happening

Comment: Multiple webparts on the page where you added the list?

Comment: Oh, the displayform. My apologies. Give me a little moment

Comment: thanks buddy . it could be helpful ,but i cant play with the dispform.aspx, bcoz i have other custom webparts on it . and i doubt that it could mess up the things . i just want a simple script to pick one control and hide it .

Comment: You cannot really tinker to much with the default forms, instead you are creating a new one which gives you more options to change the style. This action does not remove the default forms.

I would say, create a new custom display form, make the change and add the extra custom webparts. At a worst scenario you can just delete the new form you created.

Comment: You should be able to hide it with jQuery or such, but i know nothing about it sadly.

Comment: Dude i found a very simple solution for this . I used sharepoint manager tool and it allows u to select particular field to be displayed in which form .damn simple . And thanks for ur help